# Meaning of status fields in sensor_msgs/NavSatStatus

Tags: ros-melodic, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [NavSatStatus](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatStatus.html) message has a field for status, with 4 options: No fix, fix, fix with satellite augmentation, fix with ground-based augmentation. No fix and fix make sense, but what is the meaning of the field with augmentation? Notably, any Navsat/GNSS system would be satellite augmented, wouldn't it? Does ground-based augmentation refer to RTK?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319109/meaning-of-status-fields-in-sensor_msgs/navsatstatus/) by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-21**:
Not an answer, but: see [sensor_msgs/Reviews/2010-05-31 GPS Proposal_API_Review](http://wiki.ros.org/sensor_msgs/Reviews/2010-05-31%20GPS%20Proposal_API_Review?highlight=%28PackageReviewCategory%29) for the API proposal and review of the GPS messages in `sensor_msgs`. Might provide some insight into the design process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, I have learned some things through research about various GNSS types. I didn't find any of this in the ROS documentation, but it matches the field names.

No Fix means that it can't find a location.

Fix means that it found a location, using solely GPS/GLONASS/etc.

Fix with ground-based augmentation means fix with assistance of such networks as DGPS or GBAS.

Fix with satellite-based augmentation means fix with assistance of such networks as StarFire. These systems work like ground-based augmentation, but with satellites.

It appears that with improvements to GNSS systems and the end of selective availability that these systems are used less now, which is why my initial research didn't come up with this.

---

Originally posted by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) with karma: 110 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3